# Matrix-convexity of inverse of the cofactor matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix-valued function $f(A) = \frac{A}{\det(A)}$ on the set of $3\times 3$ positive-definite matrices. Is this function matrix-convex ? (i.e., Is $tf(A) + (1-t)f(B) - f(tA+(1-t)B)$ positive definite $\forall \ t \in [0,1]$?)

Comment: Cross-posted and answered on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196460/matrix-convexity-of-inverse-of-the-cofactor-matrix